# Common latin phrase for "and the opposite case too"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, english

I recall once seeing in some notes (not for Latin) which contained a Latin phrase - I can't recall the exact definition but contextually I knew it meant something along the lines of "and the reverse case is also true"

e.g. instead of saying

> Increasing A decreases the level of B. Decreasing A increases the level of B. /  Increasing A decreases the level of B, and the opposite for a decrease in A.

one could instead write:

> Increasing A decreases the level of B, `<phrase>`

The usage was similar to "vice versa" but I don't believe vice versa is technically correct here. "Increasing A decreases B and vice versa" would imply decreasing B increases A, which isn't necessarily true and in any case doesn't capture the idea of the opposite case.

Thanks!

edit: and if no concise phrase is commonly known, what would be an appropriate invention? It sounds like a very useful idiom!

Comment: Do you mean "and vice versa"?

Comment: The problem with "and the reverse case is also true" is exactly the same as with *vice versā* - the most obvious way to understand it is by flipping around the causal relationship (B>A), and not reverting the polarity of the action (increase>decrease). Compare [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390591) on the English SE, where the OP distinguishes between "converse" and "reverse" only to receive an answer that "conversely" is exactly what they're looking for. I think therefore the problem is logical rather than linguistic. Moreover, your question may be about English not Latin